# Found a dependency cycle in dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I try to provide fragment with `DatePickerDialog` , but when i use the `BasicInfoFragment` as argument it cause the error : `Found a dependency cycle` 
why that happen ?!

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(val activity: AppCompatActivity) {

    @Provides
    fun provideActivity() = activity

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    fun provideContext(): Context = activity

    // [...]
    @Provides
    fun provideDatePickerDialog(basicInfoFragment: BasicInfoFragment): 
    DatePickerDialog {
        return DatePickerDialog(activity, basicInfoFragment, 1999, 9, 9)
    }
}
```

Fragment code :

```
class BasicInfoFragment @Inject constructor()
    : BaseFragment(), BasicInfoMvpView , 
      LabelledSpinner.OnItemChosenListener, 
      DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Inject
    lateinit var datePickerDialog: DatePickerDialog

    @Inject
    lateinit var mPresenter: BasicInfoMvpPresenter<BasicInfoMvpView>

    // user info
    private lateinit var gender: DataManager.UserGender
    private var birthOfDate: Long = 0L


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_user_info_layout, container, false)

        activityComponent?.let {
            it.inject(this)
            mPresenter.onAttach(this)
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onDateSet(dataPicker: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        birthOfDate = GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth).timeInMillis
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `provideDatePickerDialog` you need a `BasicInfoFragment`, but then when you also try to inject a `DatePickerDialog` in `BasicInfoFragment`. Hence the chicken or egg problem - to create either of them you need the other.

Something else to take into account: in the constructor of the DateTimePicker you really need the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` not the `BasicInfoFragment`.

**Solution 1**

Change the provideDatePickerDialog as follows

```
@Provides
fun provideDatePickerDialog(basicInfoFragment: BasicInfoFragment): 
DatePickerDialog {
    return DatePickerDialog(activity)
}
```

then set the listener and the date in the fragment. See documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int))

**Solution 2**

Don't provide the DatePickerDialog with Dagger but instead create it in the BasicInfoFragment with this line:

```
DatePickerDialog(activity, this, 1999, 9, 9)
```

This way you will also eliminate other possible issues and confusions.

Comment: Before everything  THANK YOU , solution 1 : Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): new android.app.DatePickerDialog  . I will use Solution 2

Comment: Unfortunately NO.

Comment: did you remove provideDatePickerDialog from the ActivityModule?

Comment: Yes , I solution 2 it's work fine but there is no DI in this solution